# How to use merge in Rails 4 join operation correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-4, law-of-demeter

I do have a following code structure:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  scope :order_by_year, -> { joins(:state).merge(State.order_by_year) }
  ...

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :financial_statement
  has_many :assets
  scope :order_by_year, -> { joins(:financial_statement).merge(FinancialStatement.order_by_year) }
  ...  

class FinancialStatement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :financial_year
  has_many :states
  scope :order_by_year, -> { joins(:financial_year).merge(FinancialYear.order_by_year) }
  ...

class FinancialYear < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :financial_statements
  scope :order_by_year, -> { order("financial_years.year DESC") }
  ...
```

I'd like to be able to call Asset model like this:

```
Asset.order_by_year
```

I'm trying to follow Law of Demeter and therefore Asset model should not know about FinancialYear (which holds the year information). I'm trying to use merge to accomplish this.

```
Asset.order_by_year creates the following sql:

1: SELECT `assets`.* FROM `assets` 
2: INNER JOIN `states` ON `states`.`id` = `assets`.`state_id` 
3: LEFT OUTER JOIN `financial_years` ON `financial_years`.`id` = `financial_statements`.`financial_year_id` 
4: LEFT OUTER JOIN `financial_statements` ON `financial_statements`.`id` = `states`.`financial_statement_id`  
5: ORDER BY financial_years.year DESC
```

This gives error message because rows 3 and 4 are in wrong order. Any idea why Rails creates the query this way? Any idea how to change this structure in order to get it work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't. Query will be created in wrong order and long chains like that will not work. If I remember correctly 3 stages is fine and 4th one goes wrong.

Comment: :/ ok thanks for the additional insight.